# .gitignore References and Others

Tags: git, build

So I have a C++ Project where we use the `Boost` library using `NuGet`. Problem is, when other members try to use the same, all except the member that used `Boost` gets failed build and `*.hpp` file not found errors.

So we planned to `.gitignore` reference files, i.e. commit to git `only` the code files (`.h` and `.cpp`) and nothing else, as ours is a simple school project with no fancy builds, installers, scripts, etc. So this will atleast help us use our specific builds locally.

How can this be done using the `.gitignore`? Or is there a better way to handle this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [gitignore documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore):

```
# exclude everything except directory foo/bar
/*
!/foo
/foo/*
!/foo/bar
```

This can be extended to file extensions like this:

```
# ignore everything except .h and .cpp files in foo  
/*
!/foo
/foo/*
!/foo/*.h
!/foo/*.cpp
```